# How do I configure my static DNS in interfaces?

Tags: dns

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file consists of:

```
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  


# The primary network interface  
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.1.58  
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0  
broadcast 192.168.1.255
dns-nameservers 66.212.63.228 66.212.48.10
```

I ran the command: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Which responded with:

```
*Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces  
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...  
RTNETLINK answers: File exists  
Failed to bring up eth0  
[ OK ]
```

Next I ran ping google.com and received:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I am not sure if my interfaces refreshed. How do I properly configure my network with my static DNS addresses?

Comment: Reboot your computer.  Do not run /etc/init.d/networking restart.  The error is caused by the default route already existing.  This setup looks correct to me.

Comment: As Matt H says, `/etc/network/interfaces` is picky about stuff already existing. You can have a perfect setup, but already have something there, and it will complain. If it is the default route it is complaining about, you can remove it by running `ip route del default` to get the computer into a state where you can hand over the management of this stuff to `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Network-manager has claimed another victim. Just delete that junk.

Answer (score 30):

As the questioner gives the contents of his `/etc/network/interfaces` I infer that he is using ifup to configure interfaces. But since he may actually be using NetworkManager, I will discuss that as well.

If you are using ifup then DNS settings go in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  For each interface you add `dns-*` options appropriate for the nameserver(s) available over that interface.  E.g., if a nameserver at address 1.2.3.4 is available over interface eth0, then add `dns-nameservers 1.2.3.4` to the `iface eth0` stanza.

If you are using NetworkManager then settings are entered in the Connection Editor (network indicator | Edit Connections...) in the IPv4 Settings tab.

Doing `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to reconfigure interfaces is deprecated. If you are using `ifup` then first `ifdown` each active network interface, then `ifup` each interface. If you are using NetworkManager then, first, disable networking using the indicator (top of the desktop); then open a terminal and run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

and then enable networking using the indicator.

Or you can just reboot.

Regarding the fact that `/etc/init.d/networking restart` resulted in

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0
```

This means that ifupdown thinks that `eth0` is already up. Use `ifdown --force eth0` to cause `ifupdown` to stop believing that it has already configured the interface.

Regarding the "deprecated" message, this message is no longer printed in Ubuntu 12.10 but you should still note that initscripts are "on their way out". To restart a service `foo`, use `service foo restart` or `restart foo`. Note also that if you want to reconfigure your interfaces it is better to ifdown them one by one than to rely on restarting "networking".

Answer (score 20):

If none of the above work, keep it mind that Ubuntu appends a `tail` file to the resolv.conf file that it generates.

Try this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

Which will open a blank resolv.conf.d file in the nano text editor.  You will need to place your DNS server address on the first line of this file and remember to end the line with a carriage return (hit enter) as seen below:

> ```
> nameserver 10.20.1.2
> ```

- You can also use Google's public DNS: `8.8.8.8` and/or `8.8.4.4`.

Editing the tail file instead of the actual resolv.conf file will prevent your change from being lost upon a system reboot.

You will need to run `sudo resolvconf -u` to activate the change.  You should be able to ping google.com after this.  Good luck!

If the command above does not find resolvconf, you can download it using:

```bash
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Comment: Sounds good, but my Ubuntu 14.04 system didn't use this tail file. So this isn't a solution in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.x LTS VM - thanks!

Answer (score 15):

All of the answers which relate to /etc/network/interfaces incorrectly state `dns-nameservers` rather than `dns-nameserver` - below should work:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.28
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
dns-nameserver 8.8.4.4
dns-search something.network.com
```

(tested on Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: Careful. I just confirmed that `dns-nameserver` (singular) *does not work* on RaspberryPi + Raspian Jesse. I found that I *had* to use `dns-nameservers` (plural). YMMV and all that, just trying to help out the next person...

Comment: Check your resolvconf(8) man page for usage and options. On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS it says you either use one or more dns-nameserver lines with a single IP address per line, or you can use dns-nameservers and a space separated list of IP addresses.

Comment: `dns-nameserver` or `dns-nameservers`?  because https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge says "servers"...

Comment: Definitely doesn't work for me. Cannot vote down, not enough points yet.

Comment: Yey, this is nice and consistent then! Sorry for the confusion, check both and check the above comments as it seems different Ubuntu / Debian / Raspian variants are different.

Answer (score 11):

**Command line version:**

You should add your nameserver(s) to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file this way:

```
nameserver 66.212.63.228 
nameserver 66.212.48.10
```

Comment: I will have to try this method in a few hours and get back to you. Do you know why I am receiving the deprecated message and the failed to bring up eth0 message?

Comment: You could use this:`$ ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`
Read more about this issue [here](http://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/).

Comment: I tried ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0 and received: ifdown: interface eth0 not configured RTNETLINK answers: File exists.  Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: @dottedquad what is you change the /etc/network/interfaces file to this:
`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 iface 
eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.58
gateway 192.168.1.1 
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255`
Take care that this: `auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static`is two lines

Comment: I resorted to setting my interfaces to dhcp so I can install gnome3.  Setting interfaces to dhcp seemed to do the trick temporarily.  As far as why I am having those issues with static, not a clue.  I will configure the settings once I get a gui up and running.

Comment: It is better to add nameserver information to NetworkManager connections (if you are using NetworkManager) as described by bodhi.zazen, or to interface definitions in /etc/network/interfaces (if you are using ifup) than to add the information statically and globally to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base.

Comment: @jdthood The OP has mentioned that is not having unity or gnome installed.

Comment: @pl1nk: Thanks for pointing that out. In that case I can simplify my comment to just "It is generally better to add nameserver information to interface definitions in /etc/network/interfaces than to add that information statically and globally to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base".

Comment: @jdthood The OP has already tried to set the static DNS entries in /etc/network/interfaces but it didn't work for him (according to his question).

Comment: The OP entered the nameserver addresses in the right way. I am responding to this answer from you where you propose to add the nameserver addresses in another way. What the OP did wrong is to run "/etc/init.d/networking restart". That is now deprecated. Instead he should do what I suggested in my answer, namely, to ifdown and then ifup all active interfaces... or to reboot.

Comment: @jdthood It seems that you have seen my comments and the question as well as the other answers! Some comments up [..] "You could use this:$ ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0"[..]

Answer (score 6):

Easiest method of configuring your DNS servers is to use NetworkManager

Under IPv4, fill in your dns server(s)

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that i do not have unity or gnome installed.  Gnome installatio is my next project.

Comment: It wont let me save this down. why might that be?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work around this on a headless ubuntu server install by adding

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

...after the relevant interface stuff in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.28
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
```

Hope this helps later users!

Comment: for `dns-nameservers` can you comma seperate 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4?

Comment: @Thufir `spaces` https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Answer (score 4):

> Note: carefull using without direct access on the machine, this will cut the connection...

I use

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

then

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

It will reset and release everything...

If it faces with errors related to configuration, you can use:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 --force
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
sudo vi /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

and add:

```
nameserver <add your router ip>
```

Run:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

I use core install of ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a subnet specification in the interfaces file.

Add netmask `255.255.255.0` to `/etc/network/interfaces` below the network line.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I thought i was going mad. Everytime i edited `/etc/resolv.conf`, it deleted my config. Turns out some total lunatic has distributed debian with network-manager, which is overwriting all my network settings.

This is how i fixed it:

1) `sudo apt-get purge network-manager`

This gets rid of this horrendous new tool that stops all the configs from working properly.

2) Edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

3) Edit /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

4) Reboot.

Congrats, you now have sane configs that work again.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `dns-nameservers` statement does nothing in my case. And the other answers are not by the book, as they bypass `dnsmasq` as it is utilized in Ubuntu.

To do this right, edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Add your nameservers to the bottom of the file:

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Restart dnsmasq to use the new settings:
`sudo service dnsmasq restart`

Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163506/187949

Answer (score 0):

You might configure that interface in an other file too, since you have more gateways.

Details are [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13896/1510).

Answer (score 0):

Most distro you can setup your DNS SERVER over the path

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and setup inside for ex [mine is like as follow]:

```
nameserver 192.168.43.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```