# Unable to ping anything but local host from ubuntu

Tags: networking, ethernet

So I have a dual booted machine (Windows10/Ubuntu 14.04). From the windows side I can access the internet no problem.

However from the Ubuntu side I cannot and have never been able to connect to the internet. I can only ping localhost.

At first eth0 wasn't receiving an inet addr but I gave it a static ip in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.1.106 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-servers 8.8.8.8
dns-servers 8.8.4.4
```

And now when I do ifconfig it has an inet addr and the system "connects" but I still cannot ping anything or connect to the internet.

Any ideas? Not a lot to go on I know..

Comment: Set it back to DHCP and run `sudo dhclient`. See if that helps at all.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I switched everything back to square one and now I am getting a "device not managed" when I look at the list of networks

Comment: I've tried changing it to managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/Network manager.conf. Then it says it connected to a new wired network called "eth0" but still no connection

Comment: In that case, [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/143819/295286) might be useful.

Comment: No I didn't find anything that helped me from that thread. Lots of stuff I've tried from there though.