# ping 8.8.8.8 works but ping www.google.com doesn't

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns

I'm running ubuntu server 16.04.2 and `apt-get update` returns temporary failure resolving "everything on the list".

- When I ping www.google.com, it responds with unknown host.
- When I ping with 8.8.8.8, I get packets sent with no errors etc.

I have tried every "fix" I can find in Ubuntu forums and all over the
   rest of the internet world and nothing works.  The `resolv.conf` is
   empty, ifconfig shows nic is functioning, firewall is off, and I
   threw away the hammer just in case.  Unfortunately, I am typing this
   on another computer on the same network but can't attach text from the
   various outputs to show whats going on. Need help on this please.

The resolv.conf file contains these lines:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

The last line is placed their by the interfaces file when you reboot the system.  This is new for 16.04LTS.  I'm thinking Windows NT4 wasn't so bad and neither was Ubuntu Server 12.

Comment: How is your system getting it's IP address?  Is it coming from a DHCP server?  It is a static IP?  Being able to ping the IP address will work without a DNS server IP setup.   But it sounds like you don't have a DNS address setup or your DHCP is not supplying it.

Comment: IP is static. I never setup the DNS server when I installed the server software.

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/143819/how-do-i-configure-my-static-dns-in-interfaces and add your DNS entry for like the Google DNS Servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: I did all that. My static ip is coming from at&t vdsl box. Im using their dns name-servers and dns-search ip's.  Only thing I can deduce is that at&t is blocking the dns querys.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe you might want to contact AT&T and see if they are blocking it in anyway.  I guess you could try replacing their DNS servers with the Google DNS servers and see if that works.

Comment: No joy. I had commented out the dns namesserver and dns serach lines to see if that changed anything. It didn't.

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`? Does your internet start working again?

Comment: network-manager.service not found.

Comment: Did you already restart your router?

Comment: Wore out the power cord restarting it.  This has got to be a problem with either AT&T, the lack of a DNS server on this server, the installation of the whole thing is broken or Ubuntu server 16.04 just doesn't like my hardware.  I'm almost out of hair and have relocated my Windows NT4 install discs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need a Name Server in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` and add a working Name Server.  Google provides  a free one, `8.8.8.8`.

Do this:

```
$ nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Place this as the first non-commented line:**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

You can verify this functionality with:

```
$ ping -c10 www.google.com
```

You can make this change permanent by adding the line to this file your `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file.

Comment: Whoopie!  Success!  excuse me, 36 straight hours banging on this box...
It worked. I even put in the at&t ip's and it worked. Thanks to all you guys for your help and quickness. (Mr. Moderator, these guys needed a pat on the back so ease up on the whole emotionless junk)

Comment: resolv.conf is not giving permission to edit

Comment: in contrast to @Ragy Morkos' answer, it worked for me also in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't ping www.google.com after chroot-ing into my ubuntu. Thanks to your solution, now I can do installations etc in the chroot-ed partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!! How do you people manage to solve these?

Comment: created an empty file with the suggested contents. It worked.

Comment: Nameserver is the correct way to set your DNS settings.

Comment: I can't make the changes permanent. How do I di that every time i reboot the line goes away.

Answer (score 6):

The marked answer actually doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.01. To fix this issue, here's what I did:

- Execute `sudo gedit /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf`
- Paste `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (and/or any other nameserver(s) you want), then save and exit.
- Add a symlink by executing `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Credits to https://askubuntu.com/a/1050280/899241

Comment: Awesome. This one worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Could you post a link to the page that told you that file resolv.conf should be empty? My guess is that it is misleading at best.

Edit that file with command `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and put there a single line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

That should fix your name resolution and the various programs that use it - ping, apt-get, etc.

You also ought to investigate why resolv.conf is empty. Perhaps your DHCP server isn't configured properly.

Comment: This is what the file contains:
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
The last line is placed their by the interfaces file when you reboot the system.

Comment: @GaryMercer please add that to your question. It's difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a problem related to DNS Server that you have specified for you system. Check your nameserver entry in /etc/resolv.conf.

The problem is , ping command is not able to identify what is "www.google.com" because your DNS server is not able to resolve it and provide google actual IP address(every server can only be accessed by its IP address)

#### Solution

Edit the entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Either provide a correct DNS server of a choice in `/etc/resolve.conf` that can resolve "www.google.com"

or yYou can specify your local system resolver whose IP address is 127.0.0.53 by adding line

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

or provide Google's DNS server IP (any one of them): 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8**
```

P.S  You can  understand better how DNS works [here](https://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/how-domain-name-servers-work/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, until I edited with the following values the file 50-cloud-init.yaml

```
 network:
    ethernets:
        eno2:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.50/24 (my static ip address)
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.0.42
            nameservers:
                addresses: [208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220]
                search: [208.67.222.222]
```

hope it works for you too

Comment: If is using [netplan](https://netplan.io/) and Google DNS servers [would be](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057594/349837) `addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]` (maybe better use [Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1](https://1.1.1.1/)) on `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and then `sudo netplan --debug apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an good idea on Ubuntu 16.04.x just overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`. The OS will overwrite it for its own most likely.

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` is usually a symbolic link to another file:

```
ls -lisa /etc/resolv.conf
1310924 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul 13  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

which means it is correct and you can edit it, but most likely another program is going to overwrite it. I'm going to guess you have NetworkManager installed. To my knowledge this service manages the content of your resolve. So you really should try to setup that one. (On other Hand NetworkManager could be disabled on you system. You might have to tell me.)

Try `nmtui` and add there the correct DNS Server. I also would use `8.8.8.8` only as secondary DNS. Your primary DNS should be a machine or router nearby your local network or whatever you have there...

Comment: No network-manager. Its a server with no gui. I did get dnsutils installed before it quit connecting to the repositories.

Comment: @Gary Mercer: how do you bring the network interface then? (ifup and ifdown?) The Network Managers GUI is an optional component. ```nmtui``` is the text-based of that one.

Comment: I bring the nic up by rebooting the system. Since its a server, it never gets turned "off."  I have found that using restart services doesn't always work because of the other inter-related components that make up all the services that use the interface.  Its just easier and most efficient to restart all the services with a simple reboot command.

Comment: By rebooting your system something "a manager" has to bring your devices. In which did you configure the static IP Addresses?

Answer (score -2):

The issue we addressed here is one that boiled down to resolving domain names to an ip address internally. Since version 15 of Ubuntu server, i believe, uses a system of dynamic configuration files that change every time the service or system is restarted or rebooted.  If the administrator makes a change to resolv.conf file, those changes are deleted when the resolver service is restarted.

To make changes permanent, Ubuntu has made a way to make user changes permanent without affecting the dynamic configuration of the config files.  The suggestion from L.D. James (above) was to add the changes I needed to make to the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file.

This made the changes permanent and solved the problem of resolving domain names error message `host not found`.  It is the solution to setting the dns nameserver in the interfaces file and then getting it to the resolver as well.  Thank you all for your supreme efforts in solving this puzzle.