# update, install, ping is not working in 16.04lts. can't open lock file

Tags: 16.04, networking, apt, dns, ping

on, sudo apt-get install x :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ample
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 98.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 ample amd64 0.5.7-8
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/ample/ample_0.5.7-8_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

*It gets stuck there at 0% [working], and finally comes with the error bove*

sometimes its showing different error,
after 100% downloading,

```
e: could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: resource temporarily unavailable) e: unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

*Now let me tell about my machine, internet connection is working properly on other clients/web clients. I can ping my university servers only, from my terminal(i.e I can ping only university server from my terminal). I can't ping 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 etc. I tried this [to solve the ping problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886359/ping-8-8-8-8-works-but-ping-www-google-com-doesnt?rq=1) I can install package from octave -forge from the same terminal by octave-cli*

another,

```
sudo apt-get update 
[sudo] password for x: 
Err:1 https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease          
  Could not resolve host: ftp.ussg.iu.edu
Err:2 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
  Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/quassel/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
  Temporary failure resolving 'linux.teamviewer.com'
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'
Err:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nesthib/weechat-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to ppa.launchpad.net]
```

Comment: *"I can ping my university servers only from my terminal. I can't ping 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 etc"* this sounds like a problem with your university's network or usage policies

Comment: No, I don't think so. I can't install/update from my apt package manager. And I think my laptop is in deadlock(can't avail the resources).

Comment: Anyone is there? Isn't this question appearing in askubuntu page? Please help, I am stuck here since a week.