# I have no internet connection except for Bit Torrent

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet, bittorrent

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
Strangely I cannot connect to the internet in any way other than bit torrent. It doesn’t matter if bit torrent is on or off. I cannot get anything on the browsers Chrome or Firefox. I cannot ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on the command line.
This is a dual boot machine and Windows runs just fine with internet when booted. Maybe the router has problems giving this boot an IP address or something. Maybe I should connect with a static IP address, but I don’t know how to do that. Any ideas?

I have tried a wired connection with Ubuntu. I have tried a WiFi connection with Ubuntu. No internet. Except for Bit Torrent.

The internet used to work. I had bit torrent on there for a long time. I don’t know why it stopped working. Nothing corresponded to it not working.

Comment: Open a web browser: Try address http://1.1.1.1 . Does it connect?

Comment: Also, try pinging google.com instead. And try simply rebooting your router.

Comment: Pinging Google got nothing. When I was on WiFi only I was able to ping 8.8.8.8 so I followed instructions of the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886359/ping-8-8-8-8-works-but-ping-www-google-com-doesnt) , set the name server to 8.8.8.8 and kind of got it working for a minute. Though I would like it to work with the wired connection.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo lshw -c network && ip a && ip route && cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I'll let your know the next time I get on that machine. I think it was an address that started with 127 and I changed it to 8.8.8.8 to get it working over WiFi. I could not get it working over the wired ethernet.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I changed it to 8.8.8.8. This is the file I changed with help of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886359/ping-8-8-8-8-works-but-ping-www-google-com-doesnt)