# Can't Change IP to Static

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

I am frustrated beyond belief, at this point. I have a simple task of changing an ip from DHCP to static, but it does not want to accept the new address. The interfaces file looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo enp3s0

iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
nameserver 192.168.1.5
```

When I perform `sudo ifdown enp3s0 && ifup enp3s0`, it continues to get 192.168.1.200. dhclient is not running and network-manager is uninstalled. I can't figure out where this ip is coming from.

**Update:**

After banging my head against the wall, for a couple more hours, I settled on this, as the configuration file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5
dns-search ***.com
```

I also created a static record in the DHCP server, for the MAC address of this interface, even though this interface is outside the record of the DHCP server. Once I did all that, I rebooted the server and the 1.2 address stuck. Not sure which process cured the issue. I know, after changing the file and restarting the service, nothing changed. It was either the reboot or some combination of the 3.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the address `192.168.1.2` is outside the DHCP pool in the router or other access point and that there is therefor no possible collision? The proper term is dns-nameservers; not nameserver. What is the exact result of: `sudo ifdown enp3s0 && sudo ifup -v enp3s0`?

Comment: First off, you have enp3s0 twice... once as auto, again as static. Second, your gateway doesn't look correct... I'd expect something more like 192.168.1.0, and your nameserver should be dns-nameservers (as chili555 points out)... and do you have your own local network DNS server at .5? Why not use the GUI to set a manual address? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/143819/how-do-i-configure-my-static-dns-in-interfaces for an example.

Comment: @heynnema There's nothing wrong with `auto lo enp3s0` - That just indicates which interfaces should be brought up when `ifup -a` is run. The `iface` stanza dictates how it should be brought up. [See `man 5 interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/interfaces.5.html)

Comment: If you do `sudo ifdown enp3s0 && ifup enp3s0`, the `ifup` command is *not* run with `sudo`!

Comment: DHCP range is 1.100-1.200. Gateway should be the default gateway and point to a device. In our case, 1.254. 1.0 is the reserved address, for the subnet. 

@fkraiem, sorry, that was a typo. I was putting sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your interfaces file is messed up.

```
# Source a directory for other configuration
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp3s0  
iface enp3s0 inet static  
address 192.168.1.2  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
gateway 192.168.1.254  
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5
```

That's how it should look like.
Adjust your `/etc/network/interfaces` with the above and restart your networking with `sudo systemctl restart networking.service` and everything should be set-up correctly.

Comment: Now, my interfaces file looks like this: `auto lo iface lo inet loopback auto enp3s0 iface enp3s0 inet static address 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.254` I moved the nameserver to resolv.conf. Ran ifdown enp3s0 && ifup enp3s0 I checked to make sure dhclient was not running... `root@ubuntu-host:/etc/network# ps -e | grep dhclient root@ubuntu-host:/etc/network#` Also, that Network-manager was not installed. `root@ubuntu-host:/root# dpkg --get-selections | grep network-manager
root@ubuntu-host:/root#`

Comment: You should edit your question with that information really hard to read in a comment. But writing into the resolv.conf won't help you since it will be overwritten. Is there still a problem with your IP I can't read it out from your comment? Also you should use systemd to restart your networks. `sudo systemctl restart networking.service`